# How to get a div that's positioned with "absolute" to always render in the same location

Tags: html, css

On my website https://com-bb-dev.com.edu the div with id `comBrand` is positioned using an `absolute` element. It looks fine most of the time with the `top` and `left` elements set however if you resize the or open the page on different sized monitors or different resolutions naturally the div shifts to undesirable locations.

Is there a work around for this behavior? I'm using the `absolute` property to get the overlay effect.

*The website may notify you that it is not safe, it is just because it has a generic SSL cert installed. This is a test environment for Blackboard located on a college campus so do not be alarmed.

*Also apologize for any slow internet users who get stuck rendering the bottom image, I plan to go back and fix that later I just wanted to get a final product to see how it looked.

Comment: It always renders at the same location for me: `top: 155px;
left: 342px;`, relatively to its nearest positioned ancestor, which is `body`.

Comment: Well technically it does render at the "same location", I guess what I meant was I was hoping it could be adjusted so that it renders in like the same appropriate way, like, for example if I resize the window it's in the middle on top of other stuff, i'd like for it to still be appropriately off to the left, fixed there.

Comment: try percent values. Hope it'll help

Comment: I resized my windows using chrome and he is right the logo div moves because is obviously what divs inside divs does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There actually is an easier way to fix your current problem then using tables*:

the trick is to set an anchor point that behaves similar to you page layout, which is centered.
use `position: absolute` with `left: 50%` and then use negative `margin-left` to move the element to the desired position.

```
position: absolute;
top: 155px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -480px;
```

- tables should not be used for styling! – if you want to use the power of table layouts always use css `display: table` mode

Comment: table mode? this was new for me. Thanks for this too :)

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem last year and the best way to fix it (I was looking at your source code) when you run a design like this is to run TABLES so they autoresize and then run DIVS inside tables. It will looks the same and do the same but the best thing is that it will work better from cellphones tablets and any screen resolution.

Some people believe DIVS are the best because it the latest tool to create websites, and they almost are, but TABLES will always be a tool to use so you just use it.

> Some people still believe Dreamweaver latest version is better than
>   Dreamweaver MX because the latest is the best...

Do you understand what I mean? Try with tablets the follow

```
<table align="center" width="80%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col"><div align="center">top</div></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">div with logo menu and links </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">
      <table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">1</th>
          <th scope="col">2</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">footer</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">rest</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/eevw3oes/6/